# WPF DrawLine performance issue

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, line, draw

I need to draw about 12.000 lines in my project. When i was using WinForms, thanks for e.Graphics.DrawLine function of pictureBox, it was fine. But when i migrate the project to the WPF -which is i'm kinda new at- i decided to use canvas, and draw line as a children on it. Turns out it is the most insufficient method. But i just cannot succeed the other methods. Here is the function i've been using to draw a line on a canvas :

```
public void DrawLine(int x, int y1, int y2, System.Drawing.Color color)
{
            Line top = new Line();
            top.Stroke = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B));
            top.StrokeThickness = 5;

            top.X1 = x;
            top.Y1 = y1;
            top.X2 = x;
            top.Y2 = y2;

            Canvas.SetTop(top, 0);
            Canvas.SetLeft(top, 0);
            scanCanvas.Children.Add(top);
}
```

When i tried to do a benchmark of my overall draw function by using stopwatch, it says there are just 300 ellapsed miliseconds, which seems fine. But what i see on the screen has a delay about 2-3 seconds. How can i draw lines on a canvas faster than this?

Comment: What is slow: adding or drawing? How do you benchmark? Do you really need [`Visual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.aspx) (talking about `Line`) facility: hit-testing, bounds, etc? Converting thousands of visuals into `StreamGeometry` should definitely help. Another (very fast) method is to draw into bitmap (by using `System.Drawing`) and simply output that bitmap (instead or onto `Canvas`).

Comment: Adding is fine (about 300ms according to the stopwatch) but drawing has 2-3 seconds delay everytime. Hit-testing, bounds, etc. doesn't matter that much, what matter is they should look like bar chart, when they(lines) line up. I'm trying to use StreamGeometry right now, and i'm going to post the answer when i succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should then rather use [DrawingVisual Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254(v=vs.110).aspx).

DrawingVisual is a lightweight drawing class that is used to render shapes, images, or text. This class is considered lightweight because it does not provide layout, input, focus, or event handling, which improves its performance. For this reason, drawings are ideal for backgrounds and clip art.

Comment: Seems better, because i don't need focus or event handling at all. I'm going to do some research about how to use DrawingVisual, thanks Neill!

Comment: You welcome, I also had to use DrawingVisual to get better performance and it works 100% better.

Comment: But it seems i can't use DrawingVisual with canvas, because it does not provide any layout right? So, how can i display lines that i've created with DrawingVisual?

Comment: See this link for you must use RenderOpen() member: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.renderopen(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi @Neill Verreynne, It's me again, and i want to ask something again. When i use DrawingContext's DrawLine function in a loop, all i see is the last line, couldn't even see the others. Why is that?

Comment: Are you sure that your XY start and end points are different during the loop?

Comment: Yeah, whenever i try to use DrawingContext.DrawLine function in a loop, i only can see the last point but i guess i figured it out. I put the loop inside of a DrawLine function instead of using function inside of a loop, and it solved. Thanks for your time, again :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at using [StreamGeometry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742199(v=vs.110).aspx) and freeze everything. Drawing in WPF is very, very slow.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Sheldon Neilson, but i'm afraid i couldn't use StreamGeometry with canvas.